# TypeError at /login/ 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, authentication, typeerror

I'm setting up user authentication for an e-commerce site and when printing

```
(request.user.is_authenticated())
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /login/
'bool' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
from .forms import ContactForm, LoginForm

def login_page(request):
  form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
  print("User logged in")
  print(request.user.is_authenticated())
if form.is_valid():
  print(form.cleaned_data)
  return render(request, "auth/login.html", {})
```

I'm expecting "user is logged in" to be displayed on the console.

Comment: use - `request.user.is_authenticated`

Answer (score 0):

Change this `print(request.user.is_authenticated())` to `print(request.user.is_authenticated)`

Now `is_authenticated` is an attribute.
[Ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated)
`